# apply different background color to the RHS of the div

Tags: html, css

I have a div as shown in the below picture and in that picture, you can see a thin grey line from that part I need to cover the whole thing with a different colour. I mean left part will have default BG colour but the right side will have some BG colour. thanks in advance

```css
.root_class {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.text {
  font-size: 3rem;
  // color: #bbb;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 10rem;
}

.percentile-card {
 
  transition: 0.3s;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 5px;
  border-left: 2px solid #ccc;
 

}

.percentile-card p {
  margin: 0;
}

.percentile-card p:first-child {
  color: #bbb;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .root_class {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .text {
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin-right: 0rem;
  }
}
```

```html
       <div class="border root_class rhs-background">
        <p class="text">Where Do i Stand Overall ?</p>
        <div class="percentile-card text-center">
          <h4>You did better Than</h4>
          <i class="fa fa-users pull-left" style="margin-left: 40px;" aria-                hidden="true"></i>
          <h5><b>60%</b></h5>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I tried this

```html
.rhs-background {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: pink;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

[image]

Comment: And, what is the actual question? What have you _tried_ so far? Where is the actual problem?

Comment: `.percentile-card{background-color: red}`?

Comment: its not working

Comment: _“its not working”_ - please stop saying things like that, no one here knows what exactly you mean by that. (Go read [ask], if you really still think that was a proper way to describe a  problem.) Give a _proper_ explanation of what issues you have, when you apply a background to that child element (which probably _is_ the sensible solution here to begin with, rather than to work with multiple backgrounds or a gradient on the parent element itself.)